# PHP and Javascript getelementbyid, how to pass on parameters

Tags: javascript, php, getelementbyid

I have a `Javascript` function that is called many time within a while loop with `<div id='c$value'>`.
When calling `countdown()` I would need to pass on some parameters. In this case `$m` and `$s`.

How can this be done ?

```
window.onload = function() {
    <?php
    $nbcounters = 5;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $nbcounters; $i++) {
        echo "countdown('c$i', 0, 7);";
    }
    ?>
}
```

the php code

```
<?php
$value = 0;
while ($value < $nbcounters) {
    $m = rand(1, 3);
    $s = rand(10, 20);
    echo "<div id='c$value'></div><br>";
    $value++;
 }
?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: You mean you want to pass countdown('c$i', 0, 7,$m,$s)

Comment: @Choco

Actually I’m passing `c$i` as a value and am trying to add `$m` and `$s` as parameters.
The result would be `countdown('c$i', $m, $s)`

Comment: you can directly add something like this right ('c$i', 0, 7,'$m','$s')  but since its in for loop same values will be passed everytime